# Change Layout position (on screen) of GUI elements of every app Android Studio or Unity

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm wondering if there was a way to move shown GUI's elements of any app on screen (for example to place them at the bottom). 
For example I would like to change layout and elements' alignment in Facebook app or Instagram without using root.
I would like to get something like "Force RTL layout" but using it to align elements from bottom:

[image: Force RTL Layout Android Developer Tool]

At least, I want get and edit GUI's elements' size and layout as this Android Developer Tool does:

[image: Developer Tool to highlight borders]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"

android:layoutDirection = "ltr" //ltr - Left-to-Right
```

or

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl" //rtl - Right-to-Left
android:text="hello" />
```